# Laravel Passport invalid_credentials on register

Tags: laravel-passport

I have a problem with Passport.
I have the messages:

```html
"error": "invalid_credentials",
"message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
```

When I try the register or the login.
Yet the user is still stored in database.
Here are my codes:
AuthServiceProvider :

```js
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1));

        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
    }
}
```

RegisterController:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


 private $client;

     public function __construct(){

      $this->client = Client::find(1);
     }


    public function register(Request $request){


     $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
      'password' => 'required|min:6'
     ]);


     $user = User::create([
      'name' => request('name'),
      'email' => request('email'),
      'password' => bcrypt('password')
      /*'admin' => isset(request('admin'))*/
     ]);


     $params = [
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'client_id' => $this->client->id,
      'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
      'username' => request('email'),
      'passord' => request('password'),
      'scope' => '*'
     ];


     $request->request->add($params);

     $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

     return Route::dispatch($proxy);

    }
}
```

LoginController:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


 //use IssueTokenTrait;


 private $client;

 public function __construct(){

  $this->client = Client::find(1);
  }


  public function test(){

   return 'Tu essaie de te loger !';
  }



    public function login(Request $request){

     $this->validate($request, [
      'username' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required'
     ]);


     $params = [
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'client_id' => $this->client->id,
      'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
      'username' => request('username'),
      'passord' => request('password'),
      'scope' => '*'
     ];


     $request->request->add($params);

     $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

     return Route::dispatch($proxy);


    }



    public function refresh(Request $request){

     $this->validate($request, [
      'refresh_token' => 'required'
     ]);


     $params = [
      'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
      'client_id' => $this->client->id,
      'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
      'username' => request('username'),
      'passord' => request('password')
     ];


     $request->request->add($params);

     $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

     return Route::dispatch($proxy);

    }



    public function logout(Request $request){

     $accessToken = Auth::user()->token();

     DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
     ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
     ->update(['revoked' => true]);

     $accessToken->revoke();

     return response()->json([], 204);

    }
}
```

So in the case of register, if the data is bad, I get the right messages.
But when they are good, I receive these two messages:
  "error": "invalid_credentials",
     "message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
Same in the case of login.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found.

I put the solution here in case someone someday have the same problem.

It just has to change the code:

```js
$user = User::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
            /*'admin' => isset(request('admin'))*/
        ]);
```

in function register(Request $request) of the RegisterController
By:

```js
$user = User::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make(request('password'))
            /*'admin' => isset(request('admin'))*/
        ]);
```

and everything else will work (including login :)).

Comment: The error caused by bcrypt('password') because you were trying to hash the word "password" not the actual user password. bcrypt(request('password')) would also solve the issue.