# How to retrieve access token with passport in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I just followed the steps in [Laravel official](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport).
i'm using postman to send post request (http://localhost:7777/my-project/public/oauth/token ) so i can retrieve the access token:

```
{
  "grant_type" : "password",
  "client_id" : "2",
  "client_secret" : "oxKBv6EnyEXeF6l4FBbkVcLgq2WPnyB9EOdlUpL5",
  "username" : "my_email",
  "password" : "my_password",
  "scope" :""
}
```

i get this error:

```
{"error":"invalid_credentials","message":"The user credentials were incorrect."}
```

even though i'm sure my credentials are correct.

Comment: how do you know the credentials are correct?

Comment: i tested them to login in my website

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it/issues/6294) not helpful?

Comment: i already consulted that link before no luck !!

Comment: Can you show us more code ? Just to check how you implemented passport in your project

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your oauth clients table in the database?

Comment: Try this - `"scope": "*"` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572239/laravel-passport-invalid-credentials-on-register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client must be setup as a password grant client to be able to use the password grant:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client

Normal clients do not have the password grant enabled.

Answer (score 1):

please check you oauth_clients table - make sure that:

1. Your client_id is correct
2. Your client_secret is correct
3. **Your client password_client value is set to 1**

Probably the problem is with that last part.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **client credentials** to access OAuth token then used grant_type is **client_credentials**

```
{
  "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
  "client_id" : "2",
  "client_secret" : "oxKBv6EnyEXeF6l4FBbkVcLgq2WPnyB9EOdlUpL5",
  "username" : "my_email",
  "password" : "my_password",
  "scope" :""
}
```

Here some documentation follow this :- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens

Answer (score 0):

**post man**

```
Accept : application/json
Authorization : Bearer token  //here pass token and token is equal to your login time token(write like Bearer space token)
```

Comment: please select if its help for you THANK YOU@Youssef Boudaya

Comment: This is wrong. The question is asking how to retrieve the access token.